# UISlider in UITableView - Movement issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uislider

The app contains content view and swipe menu view. The swipe menu is `UITableView` and it's part of the content view. In the swipe menu is `UISlider`. I added target for `touchUpInside` and `touchUpOutside` actions. When I drag the slider thumb and change value slowly, I can set value as usual. When I do it quickly then the thumb slider stuck near the start position of slider thumb and never set the value. I don't know if it's important but for sure I have to write that I register `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in content view controller (view of content view). For sure I'm adding picture of structure.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the code which you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved it. It was issue with UIPanGestureRecognizer. The code:

```
- (IBAction)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
if ([recognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]] || self.movieViewController) {
    return;
}

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    startLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

    if (startLocation.x < 25) {
        [self.menuContainerViewController reloadData];
        [self hideBubble];
    }
}

if (isMenuShown) {
    if (startLocation.x > self.view.frame.size.width - 25) {
        CGPoint stopLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
        CGFloat distance = -self.view.frame.size.width + stopLocation.x;
        [self movementAnimation:distance];
    }
}
else {
    if (startLocation.x < 25) {
        CGPoint stopLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
        CGFloat distance = -self.view.frame.size.width + stopLocation.x;
        [self movementAnimation:distance];
    }
}

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    CGRect frame = self.menuContainerViewController.view.frame;

    if (frame.origin.x + frame.size.width > self.view.frame.size.width / 2) {
        [self slideInAnimation];
    }
    else {
        [self slideOutAnimation];
    }
}
}
```

And I added into my UIViewController:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Now it works like a boss!